# Plotting multiple lines on a chart: geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to draw multiple lines on a chart, my code shows below:

```
ggplot(Data_UK_onTrea, aes(x = years, y = value )) +
  geom_line(aes(color = region, linetype = sex))
```

My data shows beblow:

```
structure(list(years = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), .Label = c("2009", 
"2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", 
"2018"), class = "factor"), region = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("England", 
"Wales", "Northern Ireland", "Scotland"), class = "factor"), 
    sex = c("Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
    "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
    "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
    "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
    "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
    "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
    "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
    "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
    "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
    "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
    "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
    "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female"), value = c(39611, 
    42188, 44874, 47665, 50100, 53018, 56121, 58005, 59600, 60168, 
    884, 996, 1114, 1158, 1256, 1411, 1480, 1548, 1625, 1695, 
    322, 366, 444, 511, 592, 633, 734, 787, 861, 894, 2149, 2314, 
    2538, 2665, 2914, 2962, 3100, 3162, 3385, 3494, 20868, 21999, 
    23102, 23995, 24542, 25686, 26289, 26773, 27376, 27662, 320, 
    340, 384, 400, 426, 453, 463, 481, 491, 509, 126, 135, 138, 
    160, 179, 181, 211, 221, 224, 236, 961, 1031, 1109, 1124, 
    1157, 1160, 1195, 1206, 1284, 1304)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-80L))
```

But when I run my code, there is no line on the chart:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmtSq.png)

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Yes，I did. But maybe it is because I am not sure how to use the group aesthetic. I used ‘group = sex' or ‘group = region’, and it didn't work.

Comment: Your years is a factor, see str(Data_UK_onTrea). Convert them into numeric. Data_UK_onTrea$years = as.numeric(as.character(Data_UK_onTrea$years))

Comment: Then rerun your ggplot

Comment: Thanks a lot. The lines are successfully displayed, but the coordinates of the x-axis have been changed to "2.5    5    7.5    10". What is the reason for this and how to fix it?

Comment: Weird? See my answer below? I can show it in years..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "years" column is a factor:

```
> str(Data_UK_onTrea)
'data.frame':   80 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ years : Factor w/ 10 levels "2009","2010",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ region: Factor w/ 4 levels "England","Wales",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ sex   : chr  "Male" "Male" "Male" "Male" ...
 $ value : num  39611 42188 44874 47665 50100 ...
```

Right now convert the years to numeric:

```
Data_UK_onTrea$years = as.numeric(as.character(Data_UK_onTrea$years)) 

ggplot(Data_UK_onTrea, aes(x = years, y = value )) +
  geom_line(aes(color = region, linetype = sex))
```

[image]

I am not sure how you end up with a factor, but you can specify stringsAsFactors=F when you do read.table, or do the above str() to check your variables.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't write 'as.character(Data_UK_onTrea$years)' in the as.numeric() so that the coordinates of the x-axis has been changed.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to just change `years` from a factor into a numeric variable

```
Data_UK_onTrea$years <- as.numeric(as.character(Data_UK_onTrea$years))

ggplot(Data_UK_onTrea, aes(x = years, y = value )) +
  geom_line(aes(color = region, linetype = sex))
```

[line graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Xdch.jpg)

Comment: Thank you very much